# Transform "for" in "foreach" in R

Tags: r, foreach

How may I change the simple "for" to "foreach" in R Language, with sample:

```
X  <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

for (i in X)  { 

  if (i == "A") { 
    print("Vogal") 
  }
}
```

And in foreach, how can I do?

Comment: what is your attempt so far? do you get any errors/unexpected behaviour?

Comment: We have a vector of specific values (A,B,C,D) of length 4. My point is about how to run a foreach with number of iterations = 4, however, instead of use a simple vector 1:4, I have to make the foreach run 4 times not considering 1,2,3,4 but A,B,C,D. Using "for", I use "in" to do that. How am I supposed to do the same using "foreach"?

Comment: Are you talking about the `foreach` function from the `foreach` package? Have you looked at the documentation? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over `X` like this:

```
library(foreach)
library(iterators)
##
X  <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
##
foreach(i=iter(X),.combine=c) %do% { 
  if(i=="A") "Vogal" 
}
[1] "Vogal"
```

**Edit:**
Apparently this works without making an iterator out of `X`  - thank you @flodel:

```
foreach(i=X,.combine=c) %do% { 
  if(i=="A") "Vogal" 
}
##
[1] "Vogal"
```

Comment: isn't `iter()` unnecessary? Or can you explain what it does?

Comment: No you're right, I just always assumed an iterator was required to traverse the object - good catch.